# Sitecore How to solve the error Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.Data.ID' in Sitecore Search

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-lucene

I am using sitecore Search API, but I am getting exception `'Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.Data.ID'.'` On this line: `foreach (var result in query)`. I am using following code:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("my_text_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
IQueryable<Person> query = context.GetQueryable<Person>().Where(p=> p.Firstname.Equals("John"));

foreach(result in query) // I am getting the exception here on this line.
{
  lbltest.Text = result.Name;
}

}
```

This is the class "`Person`"

```
public class Person : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("firstname_t")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [IndexField("surname_t")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.Data.ID'.]
   System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider) +14116726
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +14116814
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter.ReadFromIndexStorage(Object indexValue, Type destinationType) +609

[InvalidCastException: Could not convert value of type System.String to destination type Sitecore.Data.ID: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.Data.ID'.]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter.ReadFromIndexStorage(Object indexValue, Type destinationType) +869
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentTypeMapInfo.SetProperty(Object target, String propertyName, String documentFieldName, Object value) +172

[InvalidCastException: Could not map index document field to property "ItemId" on type Starco.ISK.Website.Search.PersonSearchItem : Could not convert value of type System.String to destination type Sitecore.Data.ID: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.Data.ID'.]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentTypeMapInfo.SetProperty(Object target, String propertyName, String documentFieldName, Object value) +360
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapper`1.MapFieldValuesToType(IDictionary`2 fieldValues, TElement result, DocumentTypeMapInfo documentTypeMapInfo) +792
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.DefaultLuceneDocumentTypeMapper.ReadDocumentFields(Document document, IEnumerable`1 fieldNames, DocumentTypeMapInfo documentTypeMapInfo, IEnumerable`1 virtualFieldProcessors, TElement result) +1249
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapper`1.MapToType(TDocument document, SelectMethod selectMethod, IEnumerable`1 virtualFieldProcessors, SearchSecurityOptions securityOptions) +283
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.<GetSearchResults>d__8.MoveNext() +1577
   Starco.ISK.Website.Search.Output.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\IIS Data\Starco_intra.starco.com\Website\Search\Output.ascx.cs:76
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

Config file for index:

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex"> 
          <index id="my_text_Index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <Configuration ref="profileSearch/configuration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Intranet</Root> 
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The following is the showconfig.aspx page sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx :

```
<indexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.LuceneIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
<converters hint="raw:AddConverter">
<converter handlesType="System.Guid" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldGuidValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldShortIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="System.Boolean" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.IndexFieldBooleanValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
<converter handlesType="System.DateTime" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
<converter handlesType="System.DateTimeOffset" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeOffsetValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="System.TimeSpan" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldTimeSpanValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldSitecoreItemIDValueConvertor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
</converter>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldSitecoreItemUniqueIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
</converter>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ItemUri, Sitecore.Kernel" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.Globalization.Language, Sitecore.Kernel" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldLanguageValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="System.Globalization.CultureInfo" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldCultureInfoValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Version, Sitecore.Kernel" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldVersionValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDatabaseValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
</converters>
</indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace? What are the custom fields on your template? Do you have custom field called `Id`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have updated my question with Stack trace. No I don't have a custom field `Id`.

Comment: Can you post the index "my_text_index" configuration file?. and are you able to search using another index like master or web indexes.

Comment: @MohammedSyam When I try to use the same code for another index e.g. `sitecore_web_index` Then I don't get the Exception. I have updated my question with the config file. Thanks!

Comment: Would you just update the index Id in the configuration to "my_text_index" small letters.

Comment: @MohammedSyam I don't think so this is the problem because the line ` lblOutput.Text = query.Count().ToString();` gives me `8`. Which means the index is found successfully.  But I changed it as you said, still the same exception.

Comment: rebuild the index after rename it,

Comment: @MohammedSyam Yes I rebuilt the index as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90203/discussion-between-mohammed-syam-and-kami).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the configuration is broken.

The `IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter` is unable to find a suitable TypeConverter and falls back to Convert.ChangeType. But the ID class does not have any Conversion Operators for strings so the conversion fails.

It should have found a suitable TypeConverter. It is collected from configuration, by default in the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration`. It should have a `indexFieldStorageValueFormatter` section where this line in particular is of use in this situation:

```
<converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel"                                    typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
```

Make sure the contentsearch configuration is correct and that your custom `my_text_index` does not override this part.

You could use dotPeek to generate a pdb file and debug the `IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter` but I think you'll get to the same conclusion that it does not have a converter available for this type.

Comment: I have checked the config file for `my_text_index` it does not contain the part you mentioned in the post. 
I have searched in the `Entire Solution` there is no config file that contains the line you mentioned in the post.

Comment: Can you check if you can find the line in /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx? Edit: whats in this file? <Configuration ref="profileSearch/configuration" /> if its missing the part I mentioned then you should include it there. If you remove the reference from the index config, the index will include the default config (which will fix it as well). Why did you need the customized config?

Comment: Yes I have checked, the above line occurs only one time. I have also updated my answer with `indexFieldStorageValueFormatter`

Comment: Yes but your index configuration points to profileSearch/configuration. Why? If you do not need to do anything custom applied to the settings you can remove that line and the index will use the default settings. If you do need custom settings then you try to include the typeconverters. I see Sitecore does merge default with custom but I suspect this is whats bugging you.

Comment: Its an old post but it would if nice if you can tell me, do I need to include the ´typeconverters´ in my configuration file ? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, you need the typeconverters to make this work. By the looks of it you need to include them in profileSearch/configuration or change the ref to contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration (this default config already has the converters).

Answer (score 1):

Try to update as following:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("my_text_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
 IQueryable<Person> query = context.GetQueryable<Person>().Where(p=> p.Firstname == "John");

  SearchResults<Person> results = query.GetResults();

 foreach(result in results) // I am getting the exception here on this line.
 {
    lbltest.Text = result.Name;
 }

}
```

Comment: In your solution, I have to use the foreach loop like this `  foreach (var result in results.Hits)`. Otherwise I cannot use it. But still I get the exception.

Comment: In that case you would need to change the foreach look to `foreach(result in results.Hits)` or use `result.Document.Name`

Comment: I will suggest rebuild your index and try to search using the default SearchResultItem without predicates if it works then please make sure of the index field names

Comment: @MohammedSyam Yes I did exactly the same you suggested but still the same exception on foreach loop.

Comment: If you are sure of the index fields names; please can you post your index config? and meanwhile try to use the default web or master index

Answer (score 0):

Normally that would mean that you are missing a conversion attribute from your property. But none of them are Id's.

It does look like you have the `IndexField` attributes set incorrectly tho. You don't need to add the type suffix on to the end. The Sitecore API will do that for you.

So change the `Person` class to:

```
public class Person : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [IndexField("surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Also make sure that the fields are not ID fields in the CMS.

Comment: I have also tried this solution but still the same exception ;(

Comment: Is `SearchResultItem` the standard Sitecore class or a custom one?

Comment: Also - have a look in your search log file and grab the query that is being executed against the index. Then you can run that manually either in Luke (Lucene) or in the SOLR Admin tool. It might give you an idea of what data is being returned and why the search is failing.

Comment: `SearchResultItem ` is the one from Sitecore. I will search in log and let you know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring in the Base class `SearchResultItem` when converting a string in the index to a Sitecore guid.

This would point to some rogue data in the index for the itemid field. First thing would be to check in your Search.log file to examine the actual query being run then use Luke to run the query to see the results.

It is likely that an entry in the index has a field (__group) that is not in the format for a Sitecore Guid.

Comment: Should you want to investigate using Luke or another analyzer then look for the field `_group` because Sitecore's `SearchResultItem.ItemId` property uses this field for the Sitecore Guid. You can use a decompiler to check out the fieldname passed in the IndexField attribute.

Comment: @Ian Graham After changing the configuration file, now the result is not what I want. Now my index contains a lot of other items.

Comment: @Ian Graham: I have seen `search.log` contains the line `15116 11:49:15 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene : birthdate:20150723 - Filter : `
 What does it mean ?

Comment: @rvandalen is correct you should look at the `_group` field I have updated my answer with this.

Comment: That entry means there is a query running that is querying the birthdate field. This doesn't correlate to the query you are running though.

Comment: In Luke you can look at the top terms for the `_group` Field to see what the values are of those guids to see if you have any rogue data in that field.